# How can I add the content of a page in a div with Ajax?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, reload

I have a list in my site, and when I click each of the list items, I want the div next to them to reload with ajax, so as not to reload the whole page.

Here is my javascript

```
  parameters = "category_id="+categoryId;
  var result = ajaxFunction("changeCategory.php", parameters);
  $("#mydiv").html(result);
```

The ajaxFunction() function is the regular $.ajax() jQuery function, with "POST". In the "changeCategory.php" I call with include another php file.
The problem is that the whole page is reloaded instead of only the div. I want to use this ajax function I have, cause I want to send data to my php file.

Does anyone know what should I do to reload only the div?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The code looks ok to me. If your ajaxFunction() calls .ajax() then there should not be a page reload. What are the HTML elements in your list you click on?

Comment: what did you tried - provide some code snippet here, what your function ajaxFunction() contains.

Comment: show us the full JS code (especially event you're binding to)

Comment: The ajaxFunction is ok, because I use it also to other parts, so I don't think the problem is this one? The HTML elements are <li> and I call this ajax in "onClick" .

Answer (score 1):

Try using [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) to load the div with the url contents -

```
$("#mydiv").load("changeCategory.php", {category_id: "category_id_value"} );
```

You can pass data to the url.

The POST method is used if data is provided as an object; otherwise, GET is assumed.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var parameters = {category_id:categoryId};
    $.ajax({
        url:'changeCategory.php',
        type:'post',
        data:parameters,
        dataType:'html',
        success:function(result){
            $("#mydiv").html(result);
        },
        error:function(){
            alert('Error in loading [itemid]...');
        }
    });

});
```

Also verify that when in your click event this line is written or not `return false;` This is required.

Comment: this is what I do in the ajaxFunction() actually.

Comment: @novellino I know but did you pay attention on return false; this stop your page redirection basically prevent the default event.

Comment: ok thanks for the reply. I add also the return false but does not work. I just realize that as long as the error is not in the ajax call, I may have something wrong in the div I am trying to add the result. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

you could send a query to that PHP so it "understands" that it needs to output only the div, like this:

**in your javascript:**

```
//add the query here
parameters = "category_id="+categoryId + "&type=divonly";
var result = ajaxFunction("changeCategory.php", parameters);
$("#mydiv").html(result);
```

**in your "changeCategory.php":**

```
//add a query check:
$type = "";
if (isset($_POST['type'])) {
    $type = $_POST['type'];
}

//then, depending on the type, output only the div:
if($type === "divonly"){
   //output the div only;
} else {
   //your normal page
}
```

Comment: @novellino I may have missunderstood your question, it seems the whole page is behing reloaded and I thought you meant your were getting a "whole" page from the php, sorry. If you really wanted to output just the contents of the div, then at the if/then clause of the external php, place something like `echo "<div>content</div>`

Comment: ah ok. I will try this. Although I realize that maybe my problem is in the div I am trying to add the result of the ajax call and not the ajax call itself. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The whole page is reloaded that means there may be an error in your javascript code

check it again
or try this one

```
function name_of_your_function(id)
{   

var html =  $.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "ajax_main_sectors.php",
   data: "sec="+id,
   async: false
  }).responseText;


    document.getElementById("your div id").innerHTML=html;
}
```

you can use get method or post method....

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "right.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {},
        cache: false,
        success: function (response) {

            $('#right_description').html(response);
        }
    });

});
```